# UIButton with background image from sprite sheet in table view causes memory warning?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have a sprite sheet in my documents directory. The sprites sheet consists of 256 icons.

I have a table view, in which for each row I am creating 3 buttons with background images from the sliced part of the sprite sheet.

Below is the code to extract the sliced icon from sprite. Using the coordinates known

```
    -(UIImage *)getSlicedImageForDictionary:(NSDictionary *)spriteInfoDictionary spriteImageRef:(UIImage *)spriteImageReference{

    NSString *frameString = [spriteInfoDictionary objectForKey:@"frame"];
    NSString *frameStringWithOnlyCommas = [[[frameString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"}" withString:@""];

    NSArray *frameValues = [frameStringWithOnlyCommas componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    CGImageRef cgIcon = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(spriteImageReference.CGImage, CGRectMake([[frameValues objectAtIndex:0] floatValue],     [[frameValues objectAtIndex:1] floatValue], [[frameValues objectAtIndex:2] floatValue], [[frameValues objectAtIndex:3] floatValue]));
    UIImage *icon = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgIcon];
    frameString = nil;
    frameStringWithOnlyCommas = nil;
    frameValues = nil;
    CGImageRelease(cgIcon);
    return icon;
}
```

I am calling the above method in the for loop as below,

```
for (int i = 0; i < [iconInfoArray count]; i ++) {   
   NSDictionary *currentBook = [spriteInfoDictionary objectForKey:[iconInfoArray objectAtIndex:i]];
   articleMetaData.articleImage = [self getSlicedImageForDictionary:currentBook spriteImageRef:self.spriteImageSource];
   [spriteIconsArray addObject:articleMetaData];
}
```

**The problem is,**
When I set the buttons in the table view from the spriteIconsArray I am getting the "Received memory warning" problem and the application crashes.

```
[btn setBackgroundImage:[spriteIconsArray objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**But** when I write the image reference to the documents directory I am not getting any memory warnings and the application runs smoothly.

```
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation([spriteIconsArray objectAtIndex:i]);
NSString *pathOfTempImage = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tempIcon.png"];
[data writeToFile:pathOfTempImage atomically:YES];
[btn setBackgroundImage:pathOfTempImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**I am confused why this is happening. I don't want to write the image to the documents and read it again, which may create some latency for large set of data.**

Please suggest me in this.

Thanks